# Evince pdf's, odd pages right at top, only in double sided

Tags: printing, pdf, evince

The odd pages only are shifted right to the top, and have no margin at all, so that the first line starts right under the top edge. Even pages are properly centred and have a proper top margin.

Any solutions please?

- evince prints OK single sided
- another pdf viewer Qpdfview also prints odd pages wrong.
- Libreoffice and Firefox print OK double sided
- but a pdf printed from Firefox prints badly, i.e. has this odd page  problem.
- evince print preview shows all pages as OK (so isn't accurate)
- in evince turning on or off  "Select page size using document page size" in page handling makes no difference
- printer Cannon MG5650
- Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Sounds similar to this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/861493 in the comments there is a workaround